# get selected value from option tag and store in db

Tags: php

I cant get the selected value and store in mysql
i wonder what should put in the form action while i see some say no need and some say put

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

this is completed code

```
<?php 
$db_handle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db_found = mysql_select_db("sdp", $db_handle);
$sql='SELECT title FROM club order by title';
$query= mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

echo'<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="post">';
echo '<select name="club">';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
  echo'<option value="'.$row['title'].'">'.$row['title'].'</option>';
}

echo'</select>';
echo'<input type="submit" value="Register">';
echo'</form>';

if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {
  session_start();
  $title=$_POST['club'];
  echo $title;
  $username=$_SESSION['username'];
  mysql_query("UPDATE login SET club='$title' WHERE user='$username'");
  echo "Register successfully!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify `action`, if you are posting to same page.

It seems like your `isset($_POST['Register'])` will always return false as you dont have any dom element with name `Register`. Either you change your condition like `isset($_POST['Club'])` or add a name `Register` to your submit button

Comment: THks !! I forget to put name attribute!

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
echo'<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
```

However if `<form>` has no `action` attribute specified, it will post data to the current action so you can skip it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You have code inside php tags so don't need to use 
`echo'<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="post">';`

just use

`echo'<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post">';`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it?

that would be concatenation problem.

If you given hash(#), that automatically consider current page.

```
<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>
```

to

```
<form action="'.<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>.'" method="post">
```

or

```
<form action="#" method="post">
```

or

```
<form method="post">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can leave blank to your action when your action is the same. But you want to use PHP_SELF as you described, you have some typing error. no need to make

```
  echo'<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> method="post">';
```

try this

```
  echo'<form action="'.$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"].'" method="post">';
```